# Going to gym twice a day

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, gym

I was thinking about going to gym in morning for cardio type exercises and then in evening do some weight training, my main goal is to get 6 pack and get ripped. Do you think going to the gym twice a day, 6 days a week will be best?

**EDIT**

weight : 183 pounds (83 kg)

height: 5 foot 7 inch  (1.70 m)

I started to gym when I was in high school and then on & off but now I haven't been to gym for like 8 months and just started again, I have been going to gym twice a day but that time my diet was shit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that if you're going at least 6 days per week you have at least a day or two of rest on the weightlifting.  Your body needs the rest.

The concept behind cardio in the morning is the lack of carbs in your body prior to eating breakfast will result in fat burn.  You should be getting at least 45 minutes of exercise per day no matter what.

Make sure you get enough sleep and don't starve yourself on the calories.  I suggest using a food tracker like http://www.myfitnesspal.com or even pen and paper to keep track.

Interestingly, I have recently started a similar program.

Answer (score 1):

If you want "to get 6 pack and get ripped" then you probably need to focus on lowering your body fat. Morning (fasted) runs, as siouxfan45 has said, are a good idea.

To get the six pack I'd more or less ignore situps and go for things like rounds of Thai kicks on a heavy bag, and cable work - things that work rotationally or diagonally across your abdomen as that ought to pull it all into shape.

And (sadly maybe) lay off the booze.

Comment: just as Ben says, for abs "you probably need to focus on lowering your body fat"

Answer (score 0):

There is one and only one way to get "abs".

Lose weight.

That is to say, reduce body fat.  The overwhelming way to lose weight is to cut carbs from your diet. If you want abs, that's all there is to it.

And, of lesser importance, basically reducing your calorie intake - eating well.

As they say **"fat loss happens *in the kitchen only*"**.

Regarding doing aerobic exercise - for example, say you run for 90 minutes each and every day. That will use a tiny amount of calories, which may help with your diet.  (NOTE HOWEVER that aerobic exercise literally ***makes you hungry*** ... so it can very much hurt your efforts to slash carbohydrate intake.)

Regarding weightlifting, it has essentially no connection, whatsoever, to eliminating body fat.  I'd just forget it for a couple of years until your abs look great, ie, you have a low body fat percentage.

Getting "abs" is simply about slashing your body fat percentage.  You do that overwhelmingly by slashing carb intake from your diet. **"Fat loss happens *in the kitchen only*"**

In the first instance, it goes without saying you have to absolutely totally eliminate bread, pasta, rice and potatoes from your diet - simply, never again in your life allow these to pass your lips.

(It's totally self-evident that you cannot, of course, ever eat candy, chocolate, cake, sodas, fruit etc. - zero sweets.)

Aim for 70-100 grams of carbs a day in the first instance. You'll see incredible abs in as little as a year or two.